# RelativeLayout over ListView, onclick not detected when RealtiveLayout is shown as

Tags: android, android-listview, android-relativelayout, android-tabhost, android-framelayout

I am currently a `relative layout` is shown in a `listview`. Turns out that when I click `RelativeLayout`, is always caught the click event in the `list view`.

I wanted to detect a gesture on the layout when it is being shown, but when I click, the item is selected from the `listview` that is underneath.

Anyone know a solution to this problem?

```
<TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/start_tabs_topbar" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="0dp" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="0dp" />

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp"
            android:layout_weight="0" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/playertab1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/back_artista"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/music_info"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity=""
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/artist_image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="9dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:src="@drawable/placeholder" />

            <LinearLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/playlist_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="playlist_name"
                    android:textColor="#3BBEF9"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/artist_album"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="artist_album"
                    android:textColor="#EEEEEE"
                    android:textSize="11dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/artist_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="artist_album"
                    android:textColor="#EEEEEE"
                    android:textSize="11dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/artist_song"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="artist_song"
                    android:textColor="#EEEEEE"
                    android:textSize="11dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

---

The listview as been inserted into:

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="0dp" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `GestureDetector` try calling `mDetector.setIsLongpressEnabled(true);` first and set view long clickable via `convertView.setLongClickable(true);`

Comment: when I make the gesture in an area that does not overlap the listview, the gesture is properly detected. But the gesture must be made in RelativeLayout that overlaps the listview, and when I click on any area that is overlapped, the listview is always the element detected ...

Comment: Try applying `GestureDetector` to the layout below `ListView` and `RelativeLayout`. For example, you can use `findViewById(android.R.id.content);`